# Connect a Spring boot javascript web app, developed on IntelliJ, to Chrome's JetBrains extention for debugging

Tags: javascript, java, spring, google-chrome, intellij-idea

I'm tring to develop on IntelliJ 2016.2 a Web-app based on some javascript framework that runs on a spring-boot application. Now for debugging I use the Chrome Development tool (F12 on the browser). I'd like to connect my browser to the IntelliJ IDE so that I can debug directly on the IDE. Is that possible?

I installed the Chrome extention "**JetBrains IDE Support**", that only would a host and a port to connect (eventually some CORS option). But I'm not able to debug in the IDE. In the IDE setting, under **Build, Extention, Development->Debugger** I copied the port number to the extension, and I checked the can **accetp external connections** option. But it doesn't connect.

What exactly I have to setup on the IntelliJ side? Or Chrome side?

Txs.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/debugging-javascript.html

Comment: Oh man you're so good :) tank you very much. I wasn't able to find this page in all the doc, or i searched with the wrong names. If you write it as answer I will give you the point.